# What is the .Xauthority file?

Tags: login, files, filesystem

I had a problem wherein I couldn't get past the login screen in Ubuntu 12.04. Even though I gave the correct username and password, it still came back to the login screen. I found a solution wherein I changed the ownership of the `.Xauthority` in my home folder.

These are the steps I used:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> when I'm in the login screen.
2. Change the ownership of `.Xauthority` which was previously owned by ROOT by executing:

   ```
   chown username:username .Xauthority
   ```

What is this `.Xauthority` file in the first place? Why does changing the ownership of the file fix my problem of being unable to log in?

Comment: sudo -H nautilus does not work with 17.10. Wish there was a real answer how to create .Xauthority when none exists.

Comment: [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/q/961967/158442)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `.Xauthority` (not `.xAuthority`) file can be found in each user home directory and is used to store credentials in cookies used by `xauth` for authentication of X sessions.  Once an X session is started, the cookie is used to authenticate connections to that specific display. You can find more info on X authentication and X authority in the `xauth` man pages (type `man xauth` in a terminal).

So, if you are not the owner of this file you can't login since you can't store your credentials there.

This situation usually arises when you execute a GUI application (for instance *nautilus*) with root permissions by typing `sudo nautilus`. You can avoid it (for 12.10 and older versions) by invoking the app with `gksudo nautilus`, or in any version using `sudo -H nautilus`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Much appreciated.
if i'm not mistaken gksudo is much preferred for invoking a command which probably opens a program which requires a graphical interface.
In what way that executing sudo instead of gksudo do bad in your system?

Comment: yes thanks again. I have already marked the answer. :)

Comment: This clued me into getting x11vnc going with openSUSE Leap (which I'm using instead of Bionic because of VGA driver issues). Trying to test x11vnc, I couldn't get `sudo x11vnc -forever -rfbauth /home/myusername/.vnc/passwd` to work. but taking away the `sudo` made it work! Haven't tried getting it to make me a sandwich yet.