# Ubuntu 13.10 login loop

Tags: ati, login, 13.10

After typing my password it starts to load but then comes right back to login screen.

I tried Ctrl+Alt+F_ but it doesn't work too, the screen gets black and after a while returns to the login screen.

It seems related to the ATI driver that I installed, if I could somehow remove it should be worth trying.

But without being able to log in or reach the shell how will I do it?

Re-installing the system is not an option for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem a few days ago. It may not work for you, but since nobody else has answered yet, I thought it was worth a shot. I think what you need to do is have Ubuntu regenerate the [.Xauthority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300682/what-represent-xauthority-file) file which is a file in your home directory.

This is how I did it:

1. At the login prompt change to the non-graphical mode by pressing: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Make a backup of your `.Xauthority` file:

   ```
   sudo mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.backup
   ```
3. Switch back to the login screen: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and log in.

This should regenerate the file and break the loop.

Comment: I just ran across the same problem on a Macbook Pro with ATI graphics. The .Xauthority file in my user directory belonged to root. Deleting the file solved my problem.