# Logon screen forever

Tags: ati, graphics, login, login-screen

My ubuntu is in trouble,

I changed my graphic card, tryed some manipulations, and now I get some problems with the login-screen.

I have the login-screen, normal, but when I type on password ( I am sure it's the good one, ssh work fine ), after I valid I get a black screen, some rapid text in textmode, but I can't read, and next the login-screen again.

I tryed to find something strange in Xorg logs, but I don't found. I am not sure to look at the good place.

My card is an ATI RS690. I use VGA for now, but I plan to use it on HDMI.

Ubuntu 13.10 / lightdm

Thx

Comment: [link](http://hpics.li/034fdca)

Comment: Here the image of the screen. So I see no bugs, or other problems. got from a camera.

Comment: Try this solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/146137/login-screen-loops-unless-you-login-as-guest - it [still works in 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362397/ubuntu-13-10-login-loop)

Comment: Ok thanks, it worked. The VGA is working fine now, but I still don't have any signal in HDMI :/. And the ubuntu offer me to report a problem. Apache2 crashed with SIGSEGV. And the window system is very slow.

Comment: That's great news :) We will then have to mark your question as a duplicate to direct other people to the solution. For your other issues you also may find solutions here (except the crash - this is as bug off topic here).

Comment: I have a second error, the gdm not installed.

Comment: This helped me : http://askubuntu.com/questions/146137/login-screen-loops-unless-you-login-as-guest and solved the main problem. Thx takkat ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your xauthority file ownership has changed so only you cant able login to GUI go to single user mode and change the .Xauthority owenrship to ur user  this will slove

```
sudo chown username:username .Xauthority
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Xauthority issue.

Goto command mode using this command Select Ctrl+Alt+F2.

Enter your username and password, then check the .Xauthority file it is in /home/username

```
ls -la

sudo rm .Xauthority*
```