# Missing files in /home directory after boot crash during software update

Tags: 14.04, home-directory, crash

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04; during a routine software update the PC crash for some reason. Here is the situation now:

- Looping during desktop log-in: each time I try to log-in via the desktop it loops back to the same screen.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and SSH log-ins work and I can browse the file directory.
- *Problem* ->  /home directory is missing all the files and folders! There are indications that files are still on the hard drive (i.e. disk usage ~17GB data on it etc.)
- Used "TestDisk" to make an image and PhotoRec to extract whatever I can. There are snippets of my files here and there but all scattered.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: This message shows up too: "No directory logging in with home=/"

Update: Running "lsblk" outputs

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
sda2   8:2    0   600G  0 part 
sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
sda5   8:5    0   3.7G  0 part [SWAP]
sda6   8:6    0 327.7G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk 
sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part 
sdb2   8:18   0 238.4G  0 part
```

Running df -h outputs

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       323G   17G  290G   6% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  1.3M  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G  144K   16G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Update: Running ls -la outputs:

total 116

```
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root  4096 Sep 17 21:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root  4096 Sep 17 21:37 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 14 15:53 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Sep 14 16:14 boot
drwx------   3 root root  4096 Sep 14 15:33 .cache
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root  4096 May 23 17:50 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4180 Sep 18 11:52 dev
drwxr-xr-x 135 root root 12288 Sep 18 11:52 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 14 15:20 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Sep 14 14:59 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Aug 27 10:33 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-34-generic
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Sep 14 16:14 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 14 14:56 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 14 14:56 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 May 23 17:48 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 May 23 18:02 media
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 May 23 19:45 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 May 24 18:31 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 166 root root     0 Sep 18 04:52 proc
drwx------  10 root root  4096 Sep 14 17:02 root
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  6 08:41 .rpmdb
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root   760 Sep 18 11:54 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Sep 14 16:14 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 16 18:21 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Sep 18 04:52 sys
drwxrwxrwt   4 root root  4096 Sep 18 11:54 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 May 24 18:15 usr
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Apr 16 18:29 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Sep 14 14:59 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Aug 27 10:33 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic
```

ls -la /home output:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 14 15:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 Sep 17 21:37 ..
```

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300682/what-represent-xauthority-file) help?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried this yet.  The bigger problem is why the /home directory is empty! Any suggestions?

Comment: /home was a folder or a mount point?
If /home was a mount point, try to mount this partition

Comment: Could you pls give me '$ lsblk' and '$ df -h' output?

Comment: @Sprite8bit: /home was a folder. see update in post for command outputs

Comment: Where was your HOME directory before the crash, on sda6 or sda2 (which seems to be a large (data?) partition?

Comment: It wad on sda6.

Comment: AHA, could you run `ls -la /`? What is your main goal: saving the files or reparing the system?

Comment: ls -la / outputs a whole bunch of stuff. Is there something specific I can post? Goal is to recover and saved files which appear to be on the system, but not showing up

Comment: I assume it still is, but it is either renamed, invisible, moved etc. The `ls -la` could/should give us a hunch of where to look. BTW, could you use @(myname) to ping me, else I would have to keep the window open all the time :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm, thanks for the note. Ls -la output has been added the original post.

Comment: There appears to be a `/home` directory. If you run `ls la /home` is there a subdirectory that *could* be a renamed version of your original home folder? (and if so, `ls -la` again in that folder to see if you recognize anything)

Comment: @JacobVlijm: right /home exists, but it appears to be empty and that is where all the files were stored. See post.

Comment: silly question, I am a bit lost, but are you sure your /home was not on sda2? There seems no sign of a previous HOME folder. I will look around, I remember something that could be realated.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, no it is on sda6. Thanks, any help is appreciated! I know, it is an odd situation.

Comment: One more: could you run *sudo* `ls -la /home`? does that make a difference?

Comment: @JacobVlijm, I'm logged in as root. The output is still the same.

Comment: Ah, should have read your post better, you already mentioned /home was empty :(

Comment: got the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `sudo ecryptfs-mount-private`.