# Login screen is reappearing, what to do?

Tags: 14.04

I am using Dell inspiron 3558, after opening the laptop, when I put password in the login screen the same screen appears after two or three seconds.
Please tell me what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, type (use the correct username):

```
cd /home/your_username
ls -l .ICEauthority # (that's a lower case L)
ls -l .Xauthority   # (that's a lower case L)
```

If either `ls` command returns one of these (where it shows root, instead of your username):

```
-rw------- 1 root root 242476 Nov  6 12:48 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 root root 58     Nov  6 12:48 .Xauthority
```

Then type (changing your_username to the correct username):

```
sudo chown your_username:your_username .ICEauthority
```

and/or

```
sudo chown your_username:your_username .Xauthority
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue before. It may be the same case as described in question [What represent .Xauthority file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300682/what-represent-xauthority-file).

Try:

```
sudo chown your_username .Xauthority
```

And then try to log in again.