# diffrences between commands

Tags: vnc, vncviewer

I would like to know the diffrence beteen the following commands:

1. `sudo x11vnc`
2. `sudo x11vnc -auth /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority -display :0`

thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `man` command? `man sudo;man x11vnc`

Comment: @waltinator just need the `man x11vnc`

Answer (score 0):

It is the same command so there is no difference.

If you meant: what do the options mean: the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/x11vnc) explains it like this:

```
Options
```

> `-display disp`
>
> X11 server display to connect to, usually :0. 
>       The X server process must be running on same machine and support MIT-SHM.
>       Equivalent to setting the DISPLAY environment variable to disp.
>
> `-auth file`
>
> Set the X authority file to be file, equivalent to setting the XAUTHORITY 
>   environment variable to file before startup. 
>   Same as `-xauth file`. See [xsecurity(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/xsecurity) , [xauth(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xauth) man pages for more info.

Related:

- [What does display:0 mean](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/what-does-display-0-0-actually-mean)
- [What is the .Xauthority file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300682/what-is-the-xauthority-file)

Comment: so probably using `sudo x11vnc` is the default command which called `sudo x11vnc -auth /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority -display :0`